# Apollo MQ and stomp.py

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp, apollo

There is some way to connect to Apollo MQ autheticated channels using stomp.py library?

We migrated from ActiveMQ to ApolloMQ and all our listeners can't connect to Apollo queues.

Comment: Can you add some information? Can you access the destinations with the Apollo JMS client? If yes, what is the JMS destination name and type? How does the STOMP subcsribe frame look like?